# iPhone Dev, 3G Testing Device Launch Failures After App Rename and Upgrade to XCode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4, rename, 3g

I have an iPhone app in the app store that I wanted to rename and make universal.  I have done all the work for the rename (renamed the PRODUCT_NAME, not the binary identifier) and adding iPad support.  Everything was running great on my iPad 2 (4.3.3) and my iPhone 4G (4.3.3).  Before I packaged it up, I ran a test on my iPhone 3G (3.0).

I cannot get my app to launch properly on the 3G.  When the app launches, the launch screen is displayed as it should be.  The screen then goes to black with the status bar on the very top, like it has loaded a black nib or something.  There are no error codes whatsoever -- nothing in the console, nothing in a pop up.  The application does not even reach the "applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method of my appDelegate.  The application doesn't crash, either.  It just sits there like it's waiting on input from a user, but like I said the application hasn't even finished launching.

The only things that have changed since the last time I tested on the old 3G (which was the last time I updated my app) are the application rename and the upgrade to XCode 4 w/base SDK 4.3.

In my XCode Scheme drop down, it does say: iPhone (3.0, Overriding Base SDK to 4.3).  I don't know if that is inadvertently causing this hangup?  I am running Xcode 4 with base SDK 4.3.  The target deployment is 3.0.

Has anyone encountered anything like this?  I would appreciate all insight and advice to the situation.  So far I have deleted the application from my device, clean/build Xcode, delete Xcode build folder, delete and reinstall all provisioning profiles, reboot of device and XCode numerous times.

Thanks,
Brandie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have been able to determine the BEST solution (not the easiest) is to make a new project with the new project name and copy your files. Changing the PRODUCT_NAME gave me wierd results and I said "forget it, let's do it by the book".

If there is an easier solution, I have yet to find it and, frankly, given it takes me about 30 minutes (I've changed the name of an app 4 times - mostly because of name length), it causes me the least amount of grief.

Comment: The problem with that is that this app has to be an upgrade to my existing app on the app store.  Can I change all the file names (by creating a new project) yet keep my Bundle ID intact?  That is what needs to match what Apple has in iTunes Connect, correct?  At this point, I'd be happy to go through the pain of creating a new project if it would solve the problems.

Comment: Ah... well, I'll admit that I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: So your projects that you've renamed -- are these apps that are on the app store, or apps that you're still working on?  Either way, I still plan on trying a new project this evening, unless someone answers with a "I saw this, do that!" answer that miraculously works before then.  Thanks for the suggestion, and I'll mark it if works for me tonight.